# TSQL self join to get results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I run the following query

```
Select * From
(
Select 
    GUID,
    MFG_CODE,
    STK_NAME,
    parentid,
    masteritem,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by guid) r
 From Fstock Where MasterItem=1 OR isNull(parentID, '')=''
 ) a
 Where r between 4716 And 4716
```

And I get following results

```
GUID    MFG_CODE    parentid    masteritem  r
31955   369553         0            1       4717
```

As you can see `GUID 31955` is actually a `parentITEM` & I need to bring in all the children of this parent item within the same query.

For example if I do:

```
Select * From Fstock where parentID = 31955
```

It returns 3 children of it

```
GUID
31956
31957
31958
```

So is there a way to combine these two queries together, I only want to return fixed amount of rows using `row_number()` function, however those returned rows sometimes contain a `Parent ITem`, I would like to return the children for those parent items as well within same query.

Performance is very important for me.

--- EDIT ----
I got it to work with following query, does anyone have other ideas?

```
With CTE

As
(

Select 
    GUID,
    Manufacturer,
    SELL_PRICE,
    MFG_CODE,
    parentid,
    masteritem,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by GUID) r
 From Fstock Where MasterItem=1 OR isNull(parentID, '')=''

 ) 

Select A.*,F.parentID From
(
 Select * From CTE
 Where r between 4717 And 6000  
) A
 Left join Fstock F on F.parentID = A.GUID
 Order by A.r
```

Comment: Someone is going to whip out a recursive CTE for you at literally any second now :)

Comment: Ugh, sorry about that. Best way I know of to solve this problem is a recursive CTE, although others may provide alternatives that meet that requirement. Didn't realize you wanted to avoid CTE's; might want to mention that in your original post. Mind if I ask why you want to avoid them? Good solution option, it seems...

Comment: What do you have against CTE!?!? They're the most elegant and often most performant way to solve this requirement ....

Comment: marc, I will consider CTE solution as well, I dont think there is any other of doing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is crude and untested, but I believe you're looking for a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) that will combine the parent-child relationships for you. Now, natively, this does not integrate any row limitations you mentioned in terms of returning a "fixed number of rows," which I was not precisely sure how to interpret, but the basic query below should be a start for you.

```
With Products(GUID, MFG_CODE,STK_NAME, parentid,masteritem)
as
(
    Select GUID,MFG_CODE,STK_NAME,parentid,masteritem
      from fstock
     where masteritem=1 OR isNull(parentID, '')=''
    Union all
    Select f.GUID,f.MFG_CODE,f.STK_NAME,f.parentid,f.masteritem
      from fstock f
      inner join products g
         on f.parentid=g.guid
)
```

Comment: you see I use row_number() function to control the pagination of my website, my table has thousands of rows and i limit them using row_number and also ORDER BY within row_number is also important to me, if CTE can do this, then fine. as long as I can return correct rowset in sorted manner.

Comment: Well, my personal recommendation would be to not use business-layer elements to control presentation-layer elements; that is, don't use a SQL structure to control how your web layer presents data. I would propose that a properly constructed stored proc with judicious where clauses on the code generation side would probably be a better path to consider if you're dealing with issues like too many records. Just a thought.